# Error in manifes crashes unity3d build

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

Dumping the error log here. I have never encountered this error before and have no idea where to start. The project used to build fine for android before I incorporated the facebook stuff. Builds fine for iOS.

[Error log dumped in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/qHJq8zJd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search in the log shows only this error:

```
AndroidManifest.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')
```

It seems the error has nothing to do with FB sdk, but more with the fact that you're using Google Play services but haven't defined the version for it.

I don't have access to your AndroidManifest.xml but I'm assuming you have a line similar to this one:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

You need to define **google_play_services_version** in Assets/Plugins/Android/google-play-services/res/values/version.xml and add a line similar to this one

```
<integer name="google_play_services_version">5089000</integer>
```

Also you should probably change the name of the question as it's not related to FB :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Problem is I dont have a folder like that in my project. I just switched the platforms today. The project used to be a iOS game. I havent written any code that uses google play services. Do I need to add a SDK or something ?

Comment: I don't think you're forced to use GooglePlayServices, but it offers access to android apis, so you may need it in the end. You could try and remove the meta-data line from your AndroidManifest.xml and see if it works, but in the end you may have to integrate the SDK.